# Changing entry's font in a one of two indexes only

Tags: indexing, subdividing, imakeidx

I'm using `imakeidx` package in a document for learning programming. I have two separate indexes: one for the general concepts, one for all of the commands, functions, modules, etc. I use a separate `index_cmd_style.ist`file to set up the layout of the second index. I would like to use `\ttfamily` to format each entry of the commands index and leave general index entries as default.

I tried to use `\indexsetup{othercode=\ttfamily}` but it changed the font for both indexes.

If I use `\index[cmd]{\texttt{while}}`, it sorts the entry under *Symbols*. If I use `\index[cmd]{\ttfamily while}`, its sort also this entry under *Symbols* and in addition it format the page number.

However, if I do NOT use the `index_cmd_style.ist` file, `\index[cmd]{\texttt{while}}` does the trick!

Anyone has an idea how to still use a `*.ist` file to format the layout but change the font of each entry of one particular index?

Thank you for answering,
Sylvain

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[title=General Index]
\makeindex[name=cmd, title=Index of Commands, options= -s index_cmd_style.ist]


\begin{document}

For a loop\index{loop} one can use the \texttt{while}\index[cmd]{while} command. 

One could also use \texttt{for}\index[cmd]{\ttfamily for} or \texttt{do \dots{} while}\index[cmd]{\texttt{do \dots{} while}}.


\printindex
\printindex[cmd]

\end{document}
```

Here is my `index_cmd_style.ist` file content:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\large\\sffamily\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\indexsetup` does general settings for all index lists, not for a particular one.

It's better, in my point of view, to change the `\item_0` style within `.ist` to use `\ttffamily` explicitly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[title=General Index]
\makeindex[name=cmd, title=Index of Commands, options= -s index_cmd_style.ist]


\begin{document}

For a loop\index{loop} one can use the \texttt{while}\index[cmd]{while} command. 

\index[cmd]{loop}

One could also use \texttt{for}\index[cmd]{for} or \texttt{do \dots{} while}\index[cmd]{do \dots{} while}.


\printindex
\printindex[cmd]

\end{document}
```

Modified `index_cmd_style.ist`

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\large\\sffamily\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
item_0 "\n \\item \\ttfamily "
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! It does almost what I was expected. However, the font for the page number is affected by the `\ttfamily` also... Maybe an other parameter such as `item_0` exists to access the font of the page number? I did not find any documentation about these parameters in the official doc of `imakeidx`. How do you know about these parameters?

Comment: Replace `delim_0 " \\dotfill "` by `delim_0 " \\normalfont\\dotfill "`. Neither `makeidx` or `imakeidx` provide information on the parameters since the index generator is an external programme, called `makeindex`. If you have a copy of the `LaTeX Companion`, you will find some explanations.

Comment: irrelevant to answer, but for nicer (more symmetric) spacing, use a backslash after `\dots` instead of `{}` in the "do ... while" line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That's code from the O.P., not mine. I won't change anything -- the question was about the font settings, but thanks

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- no problem; your answer shows output, the question has only code.  (easier to notice this in the output.)